# Is it explained why Satoshi cannot create art?

Tags: d.n.angel

In D.N.Angel, Satoshi can copy any art that he sees but not create art of his own. Is this because he was not raised by his family (the Hikari family)? Is some other reason given, either by the manga or by the author?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it wasn't mentioned either in the anime or manga. But having him raised by his adoptive father Kei Hiwatari instead by the Hikari family themselves probably was the main reason. He probably lacked training from his ancestors so he can only create a copy of an artwork, and cannot create an artwork of his own.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is more like he does not want to.  They never directly talk about it, but both in the manga and in the anime (with more depth on the former) Dark comments about Daisuke wanting to paint to defy his heritage and mentions a similarity with Satoshi. Also, he can make artwkork and reproductions, but he does not like to ( that would mean being like his family which he outright says hates) also he does not hold his family artwork  in high regard